# Firebase/Expo: What continue URL do I use to redirect a user into my app?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

I am using Expo/React-Native in a standalone app and sending a link to a users email that the user needs to click on and get redirected back to my app.

This is the code:

```
auth
  .sendSignInLinkToEmail("<email>", {
    url: "<continueURL>",
    handleCodeInApp: true
  })
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

I can't use ***exp://*** to get back into my standalone app because Google only allows domains. I've tried using the android package name like: ***com.company.app*** but that wont work to redirect. I need to use ***exp://***.

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to redirect the user back into the application after verifying?

Comment: Have you tried  https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#universaldeep-links-without-a-custom-scheme

Comment: Hi, did u manage to get it working?

Comment: I gave up on that project a while ago. I wasn't getting the help I needed for a lot of issues I was having; even through the expo community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup either schemes or universal links.

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/

Scheme is much simpler, and can direct users to your app if they have it installed. Universal Links is where you can have it deeply integrated into the OS where things like scan QR code to open app becomes available.